# Iterate on 2 consecutive values of an IEnumerable

Tags: c#, foreach, ienumerable

For my application, I have built an iterator and I need to use each of the values it yields along with the previous one.

For example, consider the following iterator, that yields the first terms of the Fibonacci sequence:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetFibonacciNumbers(int count)
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    int i = 0;

    while (i < count)
    {
        yield return a;
        int temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp + b;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Now I want to use this enumerator to compute increasingly accurate estimates of the golden ratio, which means I need to use the yielded value along with the previous one. The following approach kind of works:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int fib0 = 0;
    foreach (int fib1 in GetFibonacciNumbers(10))
    {
        var phi = (double)fib1 / fib0;
        Console.WriteLine(phi);
        fib0 = fib1;
    }
}
```

The issues are that the first value for `phi` is wrong, as the first value for `fib0` used isn't actually part of the sequence.

Comment: Don't you just need to start the fib sequence from 1 instead of 0 ?

Comment: Why not `yield return (a, b)` from your iterator?

Comment: @Sean The Fibonacci sequence is just an simple example illustrating the issue, the iterator I actually want to use is much more complex.

Comment: @gazoh - But if you're not showing us the code then how can you expect us to help?

Comment: @haim770 I didn't think of this and it works just fine, if you post it as an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: @Sean This is a minimal reproducible example. I don't need to show how I compute the next root of a special math function to illustrate my issue which is "how to iterate on 2 consecutive values". See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return both the current and previous values from your iterator:

```
public static IEnumerable<(int prevValue, int currentValue)> GetFibonacciNumbers(int count)
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    int i = 0;

    while (i < count)
    {
        yield return (a, b);

        int temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp + b;
        i++;
    }
}
```

The above uses C# 7.0 [Tuple Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples), but you can easily convert it to use a regular `Tuple<int, int>` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the enumerating function keep track of the previous and current values and return them as a tuple. For example, in the fibonacci example it would be something like this:

```
static IEnumerable<(int Previous, int Current)> GetFibonacciNumbers(int count)
{
    var (previous, current) = (0, 1);

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        yield return (previous, current);

        (previous, current) = (current, previous + current);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this elegant approach

Answer (score 1):

[Haim770's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60741319/15498) is correct if you want to modify your generator. However, you might also want to use a general purpose method that you can then reuse with any `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
    public static IEnumerable<(T prevValue, T currentValue)> OverlappingPairs<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        bool first = true;
        T previous = default;
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            if (!first)
                yield return (previous, item);
            first = false;
            previous = item;
        }
    }
```

(And of course, if you add `this` before the parameter and put it in a static class, it'll work as an extension method)

Answer (score 0):

Some fibonacci sequences start with 1 and 1 instead of 0 and 1. So maybe that could solve your problem.

Comment: The Fibonacci sequence is just an simple example illustrating the issue, the iterator I actually want to use is much more complex.